# Finding prison records for Bodmin Bridewell in Cornwall?

Tags: england, cornwall, imprisonment, 1800s-decade

In the [National Archives](http://discovery.nationalarchives.gov.uk/results/r?_q=%22william+hobbs%22+truro) there is a record that belongs to my 4th great grandfather William Hobbs.

The Session held at Bodmin names his wife as Jane (nee Courtenay) and also Jane's sister Philippa.  It indicates that William would be spending the next 12 months at [Bodmin Bridewell](http://www.genuki.org.uk/big/eng/Cornwall/Bodmin#Correctional) (presumably not the former [Bridewell Palace](https://www.londonlives.org/static/Bridewell.jsp) in London).

> QS/1/7/190, 191
>   William Hobbs, lab., Philippa Courtenay, spinster,
>   and Jane, wife of W.H., all of Truro, indicted for assault on William
>   Jolly: Jane Hobbs acquitted. P.C. fined 1s. paid in court and one
>   month in house of correction. W.H. fined 1s. paid in court and 12
>   months in bridewell, and to enter into recognizance of £50 to keep the
>   peace, particularly to W.J. for 7 years.

Are there prison records available for Bodmin Bridewell for that period (1802-1803)?

Such records seem to be available for 20 years later:

> [Bodmin Bridewell and its inmates, 1821-1848 [electronic resource] /
>   by Sally J. Pocock.](http://trove.nla.gov.au/work/35124796?selectedversion=NBD42404461)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Cornwall Family History Society](http://www.cornwallfhs.com/) are doing transcripts of various documents (see [GenUKI](http://www.genuki.org.uk/big/eng/Cornwall/Bodmin#Correctional)) but they aren't starting early enough for your purposes. [Ancestry](http://search.ancestry.co.uk/search/db.aspx?dbid=60963) has Cornwall, England, Bodmin Gaol Records, 1821-1899 (sourced from Cornwall Record Office) but again, not early enough for your purposes. Ancestry does however say:

> Following an Act of Parliament in 1779 and built by prisoners of war, Bodmin Gaol was a prison on the edge of Bodmin Moor in Cornwall, England. Three separate establishments existed on the site; Bridewell, which was originally intended for the imprisonment of women and less serious offenders has records available for 1821 to 1848; the Debtors' Prison, also know as the Sheriff's Ward, has records available for 1831 to 1853 and for 1868 to 1879; and the main gaol for which there are records available for 1831 to 1899.

which suggests earlier records have not survived. The [catalog entry](http://crocat.cornwall.gov.uk/DServe/dserve.exe?dsqIni=Dserve.ini&dsqApp=Archive&dsqCmd=Show.tcl&dsqDb=Catalog&dsqPos=0&dsqSearch=%28%28text%29%3D%27bodmin%20bridewell%27%29) at Cornwall Record Office makes no mention of earlier records.